# How to handle wysihtml5`s br and nbsp?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysihtml5

I'm using wysihtml5 editor and having some problems with the output.

When I hit return I get a line break which is OK, but the tag isn't valid XHTML. It uses `<br>` instead of `<br />`.

The other problem I experienced is when I create two spaces. I then get the `&nbsp;` element, which makes my XML parser fail..

Anyone know how to remove these from occurring?

Answer (score 0):

The following codes provide text content(without html tags) and html content(with html tags). Who wants which of them;

```
textContent = document.getElementsByClassName('wysihtml5-sandbox')[0].contentWindow.document.body.textContent;

htmlContent = document.getElementsByClassName('wysihtml5-sandbox')[0].contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
```

And my advice is that you shouldn't use jQuery for reaching the object when you listen events like `keydown`, `keyup` and `keypress`. It doesn't work properly.

The below codes work perfect for me;

```
$('.wysihtml5-sandbox').contents().find('body').on("keyup",function() {

    var content = document.getElementsByClassName('wysihtml5-sandbox')[0].contentWindow.document.body.textContent;
    var contentLength = content.length;
    var remaining = 2500-contentLength; 

    $("#characterCount").text(remaining);

});
```