# Get and Set text content of wysihtml5 Editor version 0.3.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysihtml5

please if there is anyone that know how to get and set text content in wysihtml5 Editor version 0.3.0.
i tried with methods such as "getTextContent" but it's not working, i'm using bootstrap and wysihtml5 Editor version 0.3.0.
For example i tried with this code:

```
 var wysihtml5Editor = $('#inputContentCourrier').data("wysihtml5").editor;
 alert(wysihtml5Editor.getTextContent());
```

thank you for your help.

Comment: If you want still you should check this out; http://stackoverflow.com/a/27999511/3765109

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getValue()` method.
Like - 
`alert(wysihtml5Editor.getValue());`